# Render html tags from AngularJS object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've looked up similar questions on how to render html tags within angularJS but none of them worked for me because I am using ng-repeat. Anyone have any advice.

```
     <div ng-repeat="o in SurveyResults.SurveyQuestions">
                    {{o.SurveyQuestionId}}
                    {{o.QuestionText}}
     </div>
```

My `o.QuestionText` has data such as `<b>How well do we deliver on our promises?</b> <br />Consider our responsiveness to your requests, ability to meet deadlines and <i>accountability for the outcomes</i>.`

It displays the tags without rendering the tags.

I did try putting this in my JS file

```
    homePage.directive('htmlSafe', function($parse, $sce) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            var html = attr.ngBindHtml;
            if(angular.isDefined(html)) {
                var getter = $parse(html);
                var setter = getter.assign;
                setter(scope, $sce.trustAsHtml(getter(scope)));
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then setting html bind in the repeat as such

```
 <div ng-repeat-html="o in SurveyResults.SurveyQuestions">
                    {{o.SurveyQuestionId}}
                    {{o.QuestionText}}
     </div>
```

Any other advice?

Answer (score 1):

Just use ng-bind-html, you don't need new directive

```
 <div ng-repeat="o in SurveyResults.SurveyQuestions">
                {{o.SurveyQuestionId}}
                <span ng-bind-html="o.QuestionText"></span>
 </div>
```